# iOS decode HTML entity to string

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsstringencoding

I have this code *&#21488*, it is actually a Chinese character with HTML escape using this [site](http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html).

I wanted to change from the mentioned code back to Chinese character in the program. I tried out [NSString  + HTML Link 1](https://github.com/Koolistov/NSString-HTML) and [Link 2](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.m). With the method name ***stringByDecodingHTMLEntities.***

They both return the same result, which is *&#21488*. The actual Chinese character is "台". Kindly advise any method that I can use to convert it.

*Note: I am not really sure whether the term "HTML escape" is correct. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "HTML entity" or "HTML character entity" is the term. But note that there must be a trailing semicolon:  `&#21488;` otherwise it is not valid and will not be recognized.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the pointer! Actually the link above "NSString + HTML" is working. Just that I did not included ":" into the string. That's why I cant get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both link below is working. 
It is actually my careless mistake for missing out an character.

https://github.com/Koolistov/NSString-HTML

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.m